# iPhone - Recording audio played only by app

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudiorecorder, recording

I'm creating some application that plays sounds like piano, drums etc.
I have a recording feature in that. Its recording well and good. I'm using AVAudioRecorder.
But along with application sound, outside sound is also being added. How can I make my recorder record only app sounds.....
Is there any other class/framework that I've to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that will redirect an iPhone app's audio output to a file.

I think your only option is to use a low level audio API (either AudioQueues or RemoteIO units) and when recording write the samples out to a file (via a buffer) as well as to the speaker.

This would require you to generate, arrange and mix the instrument samples, something wouldn't have to worry about with a higher level API.

Comment: Is there any tutorial available to do such kind of recording?

Comment: In iOS5 you should be able use the sampler audio unit to do all the resampling and mixing for you, which would lighten your load.